# Lines formed mid point of sides and cevians from opposite point are concurrent

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

$AD, BE, CF$ are three concurrent lines in $\triangle ABC$ meeting opposite sides in $D, E, F$ respectively. Show that the joins of the midpoints of $BC, CA, AB$ to the midpoints of $AD, BE, CF$ are concurrent.

[image]

(Should be done by Ceva's theorem, Menelaus theorem, Stewart's theorem)

I tried by using trig form of Ceva's theorem and tried to do something similar to Cevian nests proof by connecting A'B'C' triangle but I failed. So please consider giving a hint or something and post the answer later on if I need it.

Source:CTPCM

Comment: There should be an elementary solution here using vectors and these theorems which you mention. I used to do contest math long time ago, I think I've seen this problem.

Comment: I don't know vectors more than what is used in high school physics.

Comment: You don't need much, just some classic properties like $\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BC} + \overrightarrow{CA} = 0$ and $\overrightarrow{AB} = k . \overrightarrow{AX}$ iff $X$ lies on $AB$ and similar.

Comment: I abandoned the vectors after calculating for 2 hours or so and realizing that this path is really really very difficult. Then suddenly solved it with a much simpler idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the drawing here.

[image: drawing1]

What do we have?

$AD,BE,CF$ - they intersect in a single/common point - point $O$

$A'$ - midpoint of $BC$
$B'$ - midpoint of $CA$
$C'$ - midpoint of $AB$

$D'$ - midpoint of $AD$
$E'$ - midpoint of $BE$
$F'$ - midpoint of $CF$

From Ceva's theorem for triangle $ABC$ we get: 
$$\frac{AF}{FB}\frac{BD}{DC}\frac{CE}{EA} = 1 \tag{1}$$

Now the trick is to realize that:
$$\frac{B'F'}{F'A'} = \frac{AF}{FB} \tag{2}$$
$$\frac{C'D'}{D'B'} = \frac{BD}{DC} \tag{3}$$
$$\frac{A'E'}{E'C'} = \frac{CE}{EA} \tag{4}$$

Why is this so?

Because $B'C' || BC$   , $C'A' || CA$ and  $A'B' || AB$
so these relations follow from the Intercept theorem.

Multiplying the last 3 equations and using $(1)$ we get:

$$\frac{B'F'}{F'A'}\frac{C'D'}{D'B'}\frac{A'E'}{E'C'} = \frac{AF}{FB}\frac{BD}{DC}\frac{CE}{EA} = 1$$

Thus:

$$\frac{B'F'}{F'A'}\frac{A'E'}{E'C'}\frac{C'D'}{D'B'} = 1 \tag{5}$$

Now using the inverse Ceva's theorem (for the triangle $A'B'C'$ and for the points $D', E', F'$), we can conclude from $(5)$ that the three lines  $A'D', B'E', C'F'$ intersect at a single/common point. This is what we had to prove hence the problem is solved.

Comment: Well the answer is looking awesome to me but how come we know that D', E', F', lie on the medial triangle. Is it due to the reason that B'A'||AB and Parallel lines cut transervals in a fixed ratio and here that ratio will be CB'/B'A=1?

Comment: @AryanRaina Well... Interceptor theorem... $B'C'$ must divide $AD$ in a $1:1$ ratio. Agree? Hence $D'$ which is the midpoint of AD must lie on $B'C'$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(1) 
Pick 2 vectors e.g.

$\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$

as a basis in the plane, and express all other vectors $\overrightarrow{AX}$ as linear combination of them (where X is any point on this drawing or whichever of the points you need to involve in your solution).

This means, for any point X you should be able to find 2 numbers $k_1, k_2$ such that

$\overrightarrow{AX} = k_1 \overrightarrow{AB} + k_2 \overrightarrow{AC}$

Then it's all a matter of picking good start (number) parameters and playing with the equations.

Good parameters maybe are:

AF:FB = a -> number

AE:EC = b -> number

Then BD:DC you can express in terms of a,b using Ceva.

(2) Denote:

$point\ S_1 = A'D' \cap B'E'$

$point\ S_2 = A'D' \cap C'F'$

Prove that $\overrightarrow{AS_1} = \overrightarrow{AS_2}$

If you do this, it would mean the points $S_1$ and $S_2$ coincide.

My high school math is rusty but that (or similar) should be the general idea.

(3)
Also, for arbitrary points in the plane ABCD, prove and use this lemma:

$\overrightarrow{FE} = 1/2 (\overrightarrow{CA} + \overrightarrow{DB})$

(on the drawing below F and E are midpoints).

Seems it might be useful for this problem.

[image: drawing]

Comment: How would I know k1, k2 wouldn't assuming too many variables be a problem

Comment: Well, these are hints/ideas. You need to try, probe, suffer a bit, and see what happens. But at the end some of the attempts will work :) Of course if you want a direct solution (just to read it), you will miss all the fun because the solutions usually don't say what insights took them there.

Comment: And this is a math contest preparation problem. It's not supposed to be of the form  " $2 + x = 5 $ Find x ". See especially the lemma, it might be useful here.

Comment: Ok thanks dude I will try it for an hour or so if I still fail then I will ask you the solution.

Comment: I am still unable to think how to get k1, k2 and now I want to see the answer, my brain freezes from vectors I haven't started it yet. By the way I proved that (3) theorem.

Comment: @AryanRaina OK, I will play some more with it

Comment: @AryanRaina Hm, the calculations are getting very long. I guess one needs to find something smarter, some shortcut.

Comment: @AryanRaina Oh, it's very simple. I finally solved it. One needs a perfect drawing in order to get some insights. Let me post it in another answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would do this using Cartesian coordinates.  Given any triangle, we can set up a coordinate system with origin at one vertex and x-axis along one side.  In that coordinate system, the vertices of the triangle are at (0, 0), (a, 0), and (b, c) for some numbers, a, b, and c.  The midpoints of the three sides are (a/2, 0), (b/2, c/2), and ((a+b)/2, c/2).

The medians are given by y= ((a+b)/c)x, y= (2c/(2b-a))x+ 2c/(a-2b), and y= (ac/(4b-2a))x+ ac/(2a-4b).   Show that the solutions to any two of those equation are the same.

Comment: 1) this is not quite an elementary solution (for contest math) 2) this proves only that the 3 medians intersect in a single point ...  no?

Comment: @user247327 What does medians have to do here? By the way I haven't started coordinate geometry I just know basics(straight lines and circles) and my books is asking me solve this via the theorems mentioned above.

Comment: YOU said "the  joins of the midpoint of BC,CA,AB to the midpoints of AD,BE,CF".  Those **are** "medians"!

Comment: How are they medians the don't even touch the points A, B, C